# Evaluate the integral using the theory of residues: $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\cos \theta)^2 d \theta}{3-\sin \theta}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\cos \theta)^2 d \theta}{3-\sin \theta}$$

I''m having trouble simpliyfing this into a form that will allow me to use Residue Theorem. I got it to the point where the integrand looks like this:

$$=\frac{i(e^{2i\theta}+1)^2}{-2e^{i\theta}(e^{2i\theta}-6ie^{i\theta}-1)}$$

Then I found that the roots of the denominator are

$$\theta=-i\ln(3i+2i\sqrt{2})+i\arg(3i+2i\sqrt{2})+2i\pi k$$
$$\theta=-i\ln(3i-2i\sqrt{2})+i\arg(3i-2i\sqrt{2})+2i\pi k$$

But this doesn't seem likely to be the correct way of solving this. Any tips?

---

**Update:**

Ok so I tried something else:

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$. thus,

$$\oint_C (\frac{z^2+2+z^{-2}}{4})(\frac{1}{3-(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i})})\frac{dz}{iz}$$

$$=\oint_C (\frac{z^4+2z^2+1}{4z^2})(\frac{2}{6i-z^2+1})dz$$

$$=\oint_C (\frac{z^4+2z^2+1}{4z^2})(\frac{2}{(z+\sqrt{1+6i})(z-\sqrt{1+6i})})$$

Is this on the right track?? I guess the next step would just be to apply the residue theory...

Comment: Put $z=e^{i\theta} $ and consider the integral $\int_{|z|=1} f(z) dz$.

Comment: It is probably simpler to write the integrand as $3+\sin \theta - \frac{8}{3- \sin \theta}$

Comment: Absolutely need to use residue theorem?

Comment: @Did I guess not. The problem doesn't specify.

Comment: Then, using $\sin(\theta+\pi)=-\sin\theta$, $\cos^2(\theta+\pi)=\cos^2\theta$, and the identity $$\frac1{3-\sin\theta}+\frac1{3+\sin\theta}=\frac6{9-\sin^2\theta},$$ one sees that the integral to be computed is $$I=\int_0^\pi\frac{6\cos^2\theta}{9-\sin^2\theta}d\theta=12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{9-\sin^2\theta}d\theta=12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{9+8\tan^2{}{}{}{}\theta}.$$ Now the change of variable $t=\tan\theta$ yields the solution.

Comment: So apparently I need to do this using residues. Sorry for the mix-up.

Answer (score 1):

On the unit circle, Using the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$, we get 
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta)&=\frac1{2i}\left(z-\frac1z\right)\\
\cos(\theta)&=\frac12\left(z+\frac1z\right)\\
\mathrm{d}\theta&=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{iz}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, on a counter-clockwise contour along the unit circle,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{3-\sin(\theta)}
&=\frac12\oint\frac{(z^2+1)^2}{6iz-(z^2-1)}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2}\\
&=\frac12\oint\frac{1+2z^2+z^4}{1+6iz-z^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2}\\
&=\frac12\oint\left(-1+\frac1{z^2}\color{#C00000}{-\frac{6i}z}+4\sqrt2\,i\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac1{z-\left(3-2\sqrt2\right)i}}-\frac1{z-\left(3+2\sqrt2\right)i}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}z\\[3pt]
&=2\pi i\left(-3i+2\sqrt2\,i\right)\\[9pt]
&=\left(6-4\sqrt2\right)\pi\\[3pt]
&=\frac{2\pi}{3+2\sqrt2}
\end{align}
$$
Since the red terms have non-zero residue inside the unit circle.